# How to fetch the slugname from url after rewrite the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have folder strcture like below

```
-folder
--text
---index.php
```

and I have a URL like below

```
https://example.com/folder/test/index.php?slug=slugname
```

I added below code in the htaccess to rewrite the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So now my URL is

```
https://example.com/folder/test/slugname
```

I have to get the slugname on my php page and I tried  `echo $_REQUEST['slug'];` and `echo $_GET['slug'];` but I am getting

```
slugname.php
```

I want only my `slugname`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Pleae don't delete your answer. It's working after clearing the cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep following .htaccess Rules file besides your folder named folder and try following rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I just want to know how to get the slugname on my page after rewrite the url.

Comment: @user9437856, after using these rules if you have right url in backend which is getting served then you should get right slug with php code IMHO, let me know how it goes.

Comment: I am also getting the page with my code. The URL is wotking, I have to get the slugname and  pass to the function. and using your answer I am not getting the slugname.

Comment: I apologize for my bad, It's working after clearing the cache. Thank you for the help and upvote from my side.

Comment: @user9437856, no worries, cheers and happy learning.